# Categories of 'for' loops

Tags: research

I remember once reading some research where a body of C code had been analysed, and the findings were that the vast majority of `for` loops could be categorised into about five categories, corresponding to the functional equivalents of `map`, `filter`, `fold`, etc.

I can't seem to find this paper/article anymore. Can anyone point me to it?

Comment: I found something similar on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2647704/1009414 Maybe there you will find some info about this article.

Comment: homomorphisms, catamorphisms and anamorphisms etc. might be worth a google, for loops that aren't on lists

Answer (score 11):

This isn't an exact match for what you were requesting, but I think it gets pretty close to the root of your question.

This site's page on [Loops](http://beastie.cs.ua.edu/cs150/book/index_14.html) discusses a number of looping patterns.

- counting
- filtered-count
- accumulate
- filtered-accumulate
- search
- extreme
- extreme-index
- filter
- map
- shuffle
- merge
- fossilized
- missed-condition

They also have a page on [Recursion](http://beastie.cs.ua.edu/cs150/book/index_16.html) that covers many of the same patterns in a recursive manner.

Comment: ...I was hoping "extreme" loops would be more, well, _extreme_...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've heard it too. Somewhere in the [SICP-videos](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) or the book i think I heard that most (if not all) programs/algorithms can be expressed using streams and filters. Streams starts at lecture 6A.

As for all loops (for, while, do-while and so on) they all are implemented with label, compare and conditional jump so they are just syntactic sugar to make it easier to read and understand.